# Select and update a row in an atomic operation using PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, concurrency

I have a PHP script that uses PDO to connect to a SQLite database. Let's say the database looks like this (simplified):

```
ID     A    B
1      foo  bar
2      abc  xyz
3      def
```

Now, let's say that someone accesses this script using http://example.com/example.php?b=ghi. The script should then find the first (lowest `ID`) row with an empty value in `B` and insert `ghi` into `B`.

Obviously I could just use something like this (let's pretend I have sanitized the GET variable `b`):

```
$row = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE B IS NULL OR B=''")->fetch();
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET B=:b WHERE ID=:id");                                               
$stmt->bindValue(":b", $b);
$stmt->bindValue(":id", $row['ID']);
$stmt->execute();
```

In my case it would probably work fine in 99.99999% of all cases. But there is a chance of a concurrency problem if two users access the script at the same time. They could get the same row (`ID = 3`) from the `SELECT` 
statement, and then it's anyone's guess which value will be overwritten by the other one.

Is there an easy way to work around this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688476/locking-a-row-with-sqlite-read-lock and https://medium.com/@gwendal.roue/four-different-ways-to-handle-sqlite-concurrency-db3bcc74d00e and https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it all in one single statement. Subqueries are your friend:

```
UPDATE table SET b = :b
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM table AS t
            WHERE t.b IS NULL OR t.b = ''
            ORDER BY t.id
            LIMIT 1)
```